# AJAX function not executing when invoked

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, function

**AJAX function not executing when invoked.**

```
Here is the button that executes the PHP code:
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT QUIZ" id="btn4">

Here is the PHP code that is executed:
    <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $items = array();  $j=0;
        foreach($_POST['response'] as $key => $value) {
          {$items[$j++] = $value;}
            if($correctAnswerArray[$key] == $value) {
              $rightAnswer++;
            } else {
              $wrongAnswer++;
            }
        }
        $quizScore = ($rightAnswer / (4))*100;
        $query1 = "UPDATE users SET quiz1_q1 = '$items[0]', quiz1_q2 = '$items[1]',  quiz1_score = '$quizScore' WHERE userid = '" . $_SESSION['userid'] . "'";
        $resultt = $conn->query($query1);
          if($resultt)
            { echo "Your quiz has been saved"; } 
          else 
            { echo '<h1>System Error</h1>'; } 
    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var obj = <?php echo json_encode($items); ?>;
      var objj = <?php echo json_encode($correctAnswerArray); ?>;
      var objjj = <?php echo json_encode($quizScore); ?>;
      makeRequest(obj, objj, objjj);
      </script>
    <?php } ?>

 *Here is the makeRequest function (under the HEAD section)*
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function makeRequest(obj, objj, objjj) {
      $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      url: "quiz_results.php",
      data: {resulta:JSON.stringify(obj), resultb:JSON.stringify(objj), resultc:JSON.stringify(objjj)},
      success: function(results){
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = results;
      }
      });
     };
     </script>
```

It appears that the makeRequest function is never executed. I appreciate your help! Please keep in mind that I left code out that I thought was irrelevant for privacy concerns.  Please let me know if you have any questions.
Thank you.

Comment: It isn't clear how you are tying the button to the function.

Comment: Are you expecting the makeRequest function to be called when the page is fully loaded?

Comment: you will need to add an eventListener to the button, which calls the makeRequest function in order for the Ajax function to be called correctly. Currently, the Ajax function is called when page is fully loaded

Comment: @codemax the function makeRequest is only being declared not called. There are no document.ready() or something alike inside the script tags

Comment: @ggderas maybe I've seen it wrongly. but what is makeRequest(obj, objj, objjj); on line 28?

Comment: @codemax I'm sorry I can't see the numbers of the lines in my mobile app. But I think I I know when you're aiming. Its being called but that call is not inside a function that runs when the page loads. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand the problem ....but: If the (server-side) php script sets the values for obj, objj and objjj  ...why doesn't it simply set the results of the (superfluous) ajax call instead? I.e. I don't see why the client has to send another http request to get those values?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone!  I added a little more detail as a result of the comments.  Please let me know if you have questions!

Comment: The Submit Button (through name="submit") triggers the PHP code using **if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {** statement.  The code **makeRequest(obj, objj,objjj);** at the end of the if statement is supposed to invoke the makeRequest  function.  The problem is that it does not.  All the other code before the makeRequest invocation works properly. Thanks.